# Travel from Paris to San Sebastian

Tags: public-transport, budget, france, spain

Three of us are planning to leave from Paris to spend a week in Hendaye and San Sebastian. Is it more convenient/cheaper to go by car or by train ? Any restrictions to taking a rented car over from France into Spain and back ?

Comment: 5 years ago, I went to San Sbastian and in that time the train was cheaper.

Comment: These are really two separate questions. On one hand you are asking about cheap transport from Paris to San Sebastian. Now, what is `cheap` and `convenient` for you? You'll need to be more specific or else the question will be deemed opinion-based. Secondly you are asking about restrictions for international travel when renting a car. This is a separate question and should therefore be asked in its own post. Note though that it is likely that we already covered this on Travel.SE. Have a search and see.

Comment: Paris - Irun is covered by TGVs. Then at Irun you can board a local train ( Cercanías - Aldiriak ). That would be the most convenient route... for me!